# Showing error in console and didnt load checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout

> [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Tax/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals" template requested by "minicart_content.subtotal.container.subtotal.subtotal.totals".

in magento show this error and checkout page didnt load still loading how can i fix this

Comment: Search in your layout files for the name minicart_content.subtotal.container.subtotal.subtotal.totals and make sure the path of your mentioned template file is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was missing that file and i copy that path now it works properly.